# Ajax form: OnSuccess, load partial div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have this `Ajax Form`

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("AddAttendeeManual", "Attendee", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "doneManualEmail" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <div class="form-group">            
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SelectedManualEmail.Email, new {@class = "form-control",PlaceHolder="Email"})                
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="btnManual"class="btn btn-default" value="Add>>" />    
}
```

and a `div`, both are on same view

```
<div id="invitedPeoples" data-url="@Url.Action("InvitedAttendees", "Attendee", new { appointmentId = Model.AppointmentId })">

</div>
```

Everytime the form is submitted, I wanted to load the div that should have a partial view.
This is what I have done

```
    function doneManualEmail(isRequestSucceded) {
        $(@Html.IdFor(m=>m.SelectedManualEmail.Email)).val('');
        var url = $("#invitedPeoples").data('url');
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $('#invitedPeoples').html(data);
        });
    };
```

everytime the form is submitted, i get forwarded to `InvitedAttendees` method, but my partial view doesn't show up.

The first line of the jquery works fine but the part to load partial view doesn't work.
Any thing I'm missing?

Error in Console:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using [`e.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) inside the click event?

Comment: i think instead of data-url in var url =$("#invitedPeoples").data('url'); used url this might be the problem

Comment: `$.get()` instead you can use `$.post()`.

Comment: @Jai tried `$.post`, stil doesn't work

Comment: @Rudresh what do you mean? Don't quite get you

Comment: you have the onSuccess function doneManualEmail() right?.If so you can write the code in the event in that function

Comment: @MaheshReddy i tried adding there, still didn't work, i'll update my question

Comment: do you have the unobtrusive javascript files on the page? if not it will behave like a regular form and redirect to the page.

Comment: i mean in data('url'); instead of data-url you are usin 'url' is it the problem i am asking and the general structure of $.get is  $.get(url, { data to action as parameter }, function(data){});

Comment: Does changing your HttpMethod to GET help?

Comment: @Dumisani I want to load the partialView(table) after the submission of the form. That shouldn't be the problem

Comment: @Biplov13 try  `function doneManualEmail() {
       
        var url = $("#invitedPeoples").data('url');
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $('#invitedPeoples').html(data);
        });
    };`

Comment: @MaheshReddy if you check my updated question, that is what I have now

Comment: @Biplov13  I have seen ,just try the code I've given. To make textbox empty we will see that if content loads first.

Comment: @MattTabor I have unobtrusive ajax min file loaded

Comment: @MaheshReddy didn't work

Comment: @Biplov13 Do you get any alert in 'doneManualEmail' function?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47763/discussion-between-mahesh-reddy-and-biplov13)

Comment: @MaheshReddy if i add a alert function then yes i do get alert, may be you can look the console error image i added